# kafka - missing data while application is down

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I just made spark stream application with [this sample code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala), and made my own producers through console (kafka-console-producer.sh) and file (connect-standalone.sh). Application works well with either my own producers. BUT application cannot read data which append while application is down. It is not read even though application is re-started. How can my application read these data?

[image]

Comment: Did you enable check pointing in your application?

Comment: Do you mean this? 'ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")'

Comment: yes. Checkpoint directory maintains the offset positions and restart the job from last processed offset.